# Google Sheets Script - using an array for data validation

Tags: arrays, validation, google-apps-script

Using Java, I'm trying to find the cells that contain any text, take that data and get it onto an array then use these for a dropdown data validation cell.

I've tried various different methods of creating the array but each one didn't create the dropdown cell, leaving it blank.

```
var carerList=new Array();
    for (var i=19;sheet.getRange('G'+[i])!="";i++){
    var j=0;
    carerList[j].push(sheet.getRange('G'+[i]).getValue());
    j++; 
}
var dV=sheet.getRange('G2').getDataValidation();
dV.setAllowInvalid(false);
dV.requireValueInList(carerList, true);
sheet.getRange("G2").setDataValidation(dV);
```

I want a nice little data validation in G2 that doesn't have any blank values.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro? You'd be better off  using [`requireValueInRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range,Boolean))

Comment: I didn't want to make a macro, I just wanted it all running off the code. I'm stubborn like that :)
Thanks for the pointer towards requireValueInRange. That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is having a similar problem, here's the complete code answer that I found works.

```
//sort out the dropdown for choosing carer in G2  

//Get the last row of carers  
var Gvals = sheet.getRange("G19:G").getValues();
var Glast = Gvals.filter(String).length + 18;

//make the validation work
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('G2');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('G19:G'+Glast);
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Thanks again to TheMaster for the nudge towards the right answer.